# VSTS Nuget Restore "System.InvalidOperationException: Ambiguous project name"

Tags: xamarin, nuget, azure-devops

Built a xamarin forms cross-platform plugin using bait + switch using the method found here: https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-reusable-plugins-for-xamarin-forms/.

In the process of moving builds to VSTS and can't seem to run the NuGet restore task (stacktrace is attached).

Project structure looks something like this:

```
AppUtils.Forms -> Wrappers and common code
AppUtils.Forms.Android -> Android implementation
AppUtils.Forms.iOS -> iOS implementation
AppUtils.Forms.NuGet -> NuGet packaging project (using VS17 for Mac)
```

I can build the NuGet package locally but on VSTS I can't even get as far as restoring the packages. Any ideas?

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Ambiguous project name 'AppUtils.Forms'.
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.GetProjectReferences(RemoteWalkContext context)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteRestoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAndCommitAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CompleteTaskAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<Run>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Ambiguous project name 'Biotaware.AppUtils.Forms'.
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.GetProjectReferences(RemoteWalkContext context)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteRestoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAndCommitAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CompleteTaskAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<Run>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__30.MoveNext()<---
```

Comment: How do you specify Path to solution or packages.config in NuGet restore task? Do you specify solution (**/*.sln)?

Comment: yup, you just point it to the .sln file

Comment: What's the detail code of solution file? Open it through Notepad and post the content here. On the other hand, you may try to create a new solution then add these projects to this solution and try again.